# Require assets in react's JSX?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

A completely noob question, sorry. I'm using [dva](https://github.com/dvajs/dva) to generate a project. If I want to create an `<img />` tag, I can get the SRC for the asset like this:

`<img src={require('../assets/card-cultural.png')} alt="" />`

This works properly. However, I need to generate this code:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="assets/card-cultural.png, assets/card-cultural@2x.png 2x" />
  <img src={require('../assets/card-cultural.png')} alt="" />
</picture>
```

Notice the `srcset` value on `source`. How would I generate that string using `require`?